# Sharedpreferences Context() on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I'm new to Sharedpreferences. I followed tutorial on youtube and his code works good. but my code didnot. What I am doing is make an class for Sharedpreferences. Then Another class to create the Acions on it. Then my third class to Acsses these Actions and make them work in the Adapter. Here's my code, and the error that I have.

---

**PrefConfig**

```
object PrefConfig {
private const val MY_PREFERENCE_NAME = "com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.utils.helper"
private const val PREF_TOTAL_KEY = "pref_total_key"

fun saveTotalInPref(context: Context, total: Int) {
    val pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = pref.edit()
    editor.putInt(PREF_TOTAL_KEY, total)
    editor.apply()
}

fun loadTotalFromPref(context: Context): Int {
    val pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    return pref.getInt(PREF_TOTAL_KEY, 0)
    }
}
```

**CounterActions**

```
class CounterActions : AppCompatActivity() {

var counter = PrefConfig.loadTotalFromPref(this)

fun displayCounter(buttonCounter: Button) {
    buttonCounter.text = counter.toString()
}

fun addCounter(buttonCounter: Button) {
    counter++
    PrefConfig.saveTotalInPref(applicationContext, counter)
    buttonCounter.text = counter.toString()
    if (buttonCounter.text == 999.toString()) {
        counter = 0
        PrefConfig.saveTotalInPref(applicationContext, counter)
        buttonCounter.text = counter.toString()
    }
}

fun resetCounter(buttonCounter: Button) {
    counter = 0
    PrefConfig.saveTotalInPref(applicationContext, counter)
    buttonCounter.text = counter.toString()
  }
}
```

**manifest for CounterActions class**

```
        <activity
        android:name=".utils.helper.CounterActions"
        android:exported="true" />
```

**HomeAdapter and there I call the mehouds from CounterActions class**

```
    static class CounterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ItemHomeCounterBinding itemHomeCounterBinding;
    CounterActions counter = new CounterActions();

    CounterViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHomeCounterBinding itemView) {
        super(itemView.getRoot());
        itemHomeCounterBinding = itemView;
        counter.displayCounter(itemHomeCounterBinding.buttonCounter);
    }

    void setOnClick() {
        itemHomeCounterBinding.buttonCounter.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            counter.addCounter(itemHomeCounterBinding.buttonCounter);
            counter.vibrateOnce(itemView.getContext());
        });

        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            counter.addCounter(itemHomeCounterBinding.buttonCounter);
            counter.vibrateOnce(itemView.getContext());
        });

        itemHomeCounterBinding.resetButtonOnClick.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            counter.resetCounter(itemHomeCounterBinding.buttonCounter);
            counter.vibrateOnce(itemView.getContext());
        });
    }
}
```

**Error code**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:174)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.utils.helper.PrefConfig.loadTotalFromPref(PrefConfig.kt:19)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.utils.helper.CounterActions.<init>(CounterActions.kt:13)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.adapter.HomeAdapter$CounterViewHolder.<init>(HomeAdapter.java:339)
    at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.adapter.HomeAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(HomeAdapter.java:88)
```

Comment: Why is your CounterActions class an activity?

Comment: To use context there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `CounterActions` isn't used as an `Activity`, thus shouldn't extend it (remove  `: AppCompatActivity()`)

```
class CounterActions {
```

also remove related manifest entry

but how to obtain proper `Context` in there? just get it from `buttonCounter`, every `View` needs `Context` to be created. And `View`s are placed inside `Activity`, which is actually properly running (started by system/user interaction or by `startActivity` method)

```
class CounterActions {

    fun displayCounter(buttonCounter: Button) {
        var counter = PrefConfig.loadTotalFromPref(buttonCounter.context)
        buttonCounter.text = counter.toString()
    }

    fun addCounter(buttonCounter: Button) {
        var counter = PrefConfig.loadTotalFromPref(buttonCounter.context)
        counter++
        PrefConfig.saveTotalInPref(buttonCounter.context, counter)
        buttonCounter.text = counter.toString()
        if (buttonCounter.text == 999.toString()) {
            resetCounter(buttonCounter)
        }
    }

    fun resetCounter(buttonCounter: Button) {
        counter = 0
        PrefConfig.saveTotalInPref(buttonCounter.context, counter)
        buttonCounter.text = counter.toString()
      }
}
```

Comment: WooW man! Your explanation is great, it's first time that I know this info. And I was thinking every time we need a context we should extend Activity. And yes as you said button came from Activity class. Thank you. have a great day.